# IndexOf and .splice() equivalent for objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCQTc/)):

```
var obj = {
    x: 48,
    y: 13
};
var main = [{
    x: 8,
    y: 3
}, {
    x: 82,
    y: 31
}, {
    x: 48,
    y: 13
}, {
    x: 28,
    y: 31
}];



var result = $.grep(main, function (e) {
    return ((e.x == obj.x) && (e.y == obj.y));
});

var index = main.indexOf(obj);
if (result.length > 0)
    main.splice(index, 1);
```

I understand it's an array of objects. Is there any other way besides iterating it myself to retrieve the index and then splice it?

Comment: Well `main.indexOf(obj);` is never gonna work, because `obj` and the supposed twin in `main` are two totally different objects

Comment: I know. I just put it there to show what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Ahh I see. So you mean something **instead of** this: http://jsfiddle.net/YCQTc/1/ ?

Comment: I do not understand this fear of enumeration/iteration in SO questions.

Comment: @Mathletics Haha it makes so much sense though! Seriously though, I hope people understand the iteration happens at some level (whether it be at the developer's level, or the implementation's level)

Comment: @Ian that is precisely my point ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually already have the index. The callback of the `$.grep()` method takes as second argument the index. So you could write something like this:

```
var obj = {
    x: 48,
    y: 13
};
var main = [{
    x: 8,
    y: 3
}, {
    x: 82,
    y: 31
}, {
    x: 48,
    y: 13
}, {
    x: 28,
    y: 31
}];


var index;
var result = $.grep(main, function (e, i) {
    var res = (e.x == obj.x) && (e.y == obj.y);
    if (res) {
        index = i;
    }
    return res;
});

if (result.length > 0)
    main.splice(index, 1);
```

This will give you the last index, if there are multiple occurances. If you want the first index (as you would get it using `indexOf` on an array) you need to make sure that once `index` is set, it doesn't get overriden.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YCQTc/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of the second grep parameter

Comment: If you're only looking for the `index` and not for the `result`, you should definitely not use `grep`. Use a simple loop (or `$.each`) and `break;` after you've found the index.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var index = main.indexOf(obj);
> ```

The [`indexOf` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) does compare by equality, which for objects means their identity. You can only use it if your `main` array was like:

```
var main = [{x:8,y:3}, {x:82,y:31}, obj, {x:28,y:31}];
//                                  ^^^
```

> Is there any other way besides iterating it myself to retrieve the index?

If you search for something that does not compare by equality, then no. Of course you can write a special helper function for that purpose (just like [`indexOf` is one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility)). Don't fear to do so (and you're not missing a native alternative)!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you are looking for is an associative array. You could rewrite your main array as an "associative array" (actually an object):

```
var main = {
    "8": {
        "3": {...}
    },
    "82": {
        "31": {...}
    },
// etc.
};
```

Then what you are looking for is simply:

```
main[obj.x][obj.y]
```